# Push notification with relational query with Parse.com

Tags: push-notification, parse-platform

I have seen the tutorial but its not clear to me how to handle the following problem and optimize my query. I am doing a query inside a query for each item, and of course this is not fine since I am sure it can be done with one query.

I have the following objects:

User - a User logged in using FB logging

Publication - a publication created by the user (has a field called createdBy with a pointer to the user

Parse.Installation - the Installation object to create a push, has a reference to the user.

Right now what I am doing is a query by date, looking for expired publications as follows:

> var Publication = Parse.Object.extend("Publication");
>      var query = new Parse.Query(Publication);
>      //calculate the date here......
>      query.lessThan("createdAt", expirationDate);
>      query.find({
>      success: function(results) {
>
> //here I have all the publications.
>      //Now I get the user
>      var aPub = results[i];
>      var user = aPub.get('createdBy');
>      var query2 = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
>      query2.equalTo('user', user);
>
> //and now I send the push for EACH user
>      Parse.Push.send({
>         where: query2,
>         data: {....
>       ...
>       ...

I am sure this can be done with one query but I don't understand how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second part of your query, this is still using several queries but only one API call.

```
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
userQuery.equalTo("objectId",  aPub.get('createdBy')id;

// Find devices associated with these users
var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
pushQuery.matchesQuery('user', userQuery);

// Send push notification to query
Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
    data: {}
}, {
    success: function() {
        // Push was successful
    },
    error: function(error) {
        // Handle error
    }
});`
```

in addition, you don't need to use `find()`. you can look into these methods:

[containedIn()](http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#containedIn)

[matchesQuery()](http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#matchesQuery)

[matchesKeyInQuery()](http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#matchesKeyInQuery)

Comment: Thanks, but where do I set the query.lessThan("createdAt", expirationDate); since the Query doesnt include the Publication Object ?

Comment: You should set this in the query that gets you the list of publication still. Then, use the matchesKeyInQuery() method to build the relational query to the users.